# Align menu elements vertically higher up

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align 2 of the menu elements (Services & About) higher up but I can't.
Do you know how to align them higher up vertically?

```css
ul#menu {
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  display: table-row;
}

ul#menu li {
  display: table-cell;
  /*   height: 30px;  */
  width: 100px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  /*   border-right: 1px solid #ccc;    */
}

ul#menu li.elements {
  height: 10px;
  /* margin-bottom: 45px; */
}

ul#menu li:last-child {
  border-right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<ul id="menu">
  <li style="height:40px;">
    <a href="../index.php"><img src="./bilder/logo2.jpg" alt="Start"></a>
  </li>
  <li class="elements">Services</li>
  <li class="elements">About</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Base on your code just replace the vertical-align from bottom to top and its will be work...

```css
ul#menu {
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
    display: table-row;   
}

ul#menu li {
    display: table-cell;
 /*   height: 30px;  */
    width: 100px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    vertical-align: top;   
 /*   border-right: 1px solid #ccc;    */ 
}

ul#menu li.elements
 {
 height: 10px;
 /* margin-bottom: 45px; */ 
}

ul#menu li:last-child {
    border-right: 0px;    
}
```

```html
<ul id="menu">
    <li style="height:40px;"><a href="../index.php"><img src="./bilder/logo2.jpg" alt="Start"></a></li>
    <li class="elements">Services</li>
    <li class="elements">About</li>
</ul>
```

Notes:

1. I prefer to use padding neted of put a static height every where..
2. If you need the services and about only to be above just move the vertical algin to ul#menu li.elements with top and keep ul#menu li as is...
3. You can reduce the level of selectors, no need to write ul#menu alawyes, you can just write #menu...
4. I prefer to read about flex and try to write menu with flex style nested of table row and table cell

Answer (score 0):

I found out that I can use padding-bottom in ul#menu li.elements and now it works perfect. After adding padding-bottom: 4px; it jumps up 4 px on the 2 elements :).
Thanks for tips!